# Securely transmit commands between PIC microcontrollers using nRF24L01 module

Tags: security, wireless, pic

I have created a small wireless network using a few PIC microcontrollers and nRF24L01 wireless RF modules. One of the PICs is PIC18F46K22 and it is used as the main controller which sends commands to all other PICs. All other (slave) microcontrollers are PIC16F1454, there are 5 of them so far. These slave controllers are attached to various devices (mostly lights). The main microcontroller is used to transmit commands to those devices, such as turn lights on or off. These devices also report the status of the attached devices back to the main controller witch then displays it on an LCD screen.  This whole setup is working perfectly fine.

The problem is that anybody who has these cheap nRF24L01 modules could simply listen to the commands which are being sent by the main controller and then repeat them to control the devices.

Encrypting the commands wouldn’t be helpful as these are simple instructions and if encrypted they will always look the same, and one does not need to decrypt it to be able to retransmit the message.

So how would I implement a level of security in this system?

Answer (score 5):

What you're trying to do is to prevent [replay attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Replay_attack).  The general solution to this involves two things:

1. Include a timestamp and/or a running message number in all your messages.  Reject messages that are too old or that arrive out of order.
2. Include a cryptographic [message authentication code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_authetication_code) in each message.  Reject any messages that don't have the correct MAC.

The MAC should be at least 64 bits long to prevent brute force forgery attempts.  Yes, I know, that's a lot of bits for small messages, but try to resist the temptation to skimp on it.  48 bits *might* be tolerable, but 32 bits is definitely getting into risky territory, at least unless you implement some kind of rate limiting on incoming messages.

If you're also encrypting your messages, you may be able to save a few bytes by using an [authenticated encryption](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autheticated_encryption) mode such as [SIV](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5297) that combines the MAC with the [initialization vector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization_vector) for the encryption.  SIV is a pretty nice choice for encrypting small messages anyway, since it's designed to be quite "foolproof".  If you don't need encryption, [CMAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CMAC) is a good choice for a MAC algorithm, and is also the MAC used internally by SIV.

Most MACs, including CMAC, are based on [block ciphers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher) such as [AES](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard), so you'll need to find an implementation of such a cipher for your microcontroller.  A quick Google search turned up [this question on electronics.SE about AES implementations for microcontrollers](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/13275/smallest-aes-implementation-for-microcontrollers), as well as [this blog post titled "Fast AES Implementation on PIC18F4550"](http://edipermadi.wordpress.com/2008/06/17/fast-aes-implementation-on-pic18f4550/).  There are also small block ciphers specifically designed for microcontrollers, but such ciphers tend to be less thoroughly analyzed than AES, and may harbor security weaknesses; if you *can* use AES, I would.  Note that many MAC algorithms (as well as SIV mode) only use the block cipher in one direction; the decryption half of the block cipher is never used, and so need not be implemented.

The timestamp or message number should be long enough to keep it from wrapping around.  However, there's a trick that can be used to avoid transmitting the entire number with each message: basically, you only send the lowest one or two bytes of the number, but you *also include the higher bytes of the number in the MAC calculation* (as associated data, if using SIV).  When you receive a message, you reconstruct the higher bytes based on the transmitted value and the current time / last accepted message number and then verify the MAC to check that your reconstruction is correct and the message isn't stale.

If you do this, it's a good idea to have the devices regularly send synchronization messages that contain the full timestamp / message number.  This allows them to recover e.g. from prolonged periods of message loss causing the truncated counter to wrap around.  For schemes based on sequential message numbering, a typical synchronization message would include both the highest message number sent by the device so far *as well as* the lowest number they'll accept in return.

To guard against unexpected power loss, the message numbers should be regularly written to permanent storage, such as [flash memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_memory).  Since you probably don't want to do this after every message, a common solution is to only save the number every, say, 1000 messages, and to add a safety margin of 1000 to the saved value (for the outgoing messages).  You should also design your data storage patterns to avoid directly overwriting old data, both to minimize wear on the memory and to avoid data corruption if power is lost during a write.  The details of this, however, are a bit outside the scope of this answer.

Ps. Of course, the MAC calculation should also always include the identities of the sender and the intended recipient, so that an attacker can't trick the devices by e.g. echoing a message back to its sender.